# Embedding HTML inside a do/while statement

Tags: php, html, do-while

trying to embed some html inside a do statement but PHPStorm flags it as a syntax error. Here's what I tried:

```
<?php do : ?>

<?php while ($time !== $foo); ?>
```

I had a look at the syntax in the documentation for php and couldn't see an example of it being done. Is there any way I can achieve it so it looks something like;

```
<?php do : ?>
    <tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>
<?php while ($time !== $foo); ?>
```

Comment: i think the problem is the type of loop you want to use. try to use only a "while" loop.

while([...]) { [...] }

Comment: Looks like this structure works for while but not do-while: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php#120271

Add the brackets or convert to "while" and you are ok

Comment: with do while loops, be careful not to create an infinite loop in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do... while` syntax is invalid.

From the [PHP manual do-while page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) :

> There is just one syntax for do-while loops:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $i = 0;
> do {
>     echo $i;
> } while ($i > 0);
> ?>
> ```

Applied to your code, the syntax would be :

```
<?php do { ?>
    <tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>
<?php } while ($time !== $foo); ?>
```

You can also use a simple `while` loop :

```
<?php while ($time !== $foo) { ?>
    <tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Or

```
<?php while ($time !== $foo) : ?>
    <tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah but that syntax is invalid in the case of a `do... while` loop. Beware though, as @user2831723 sharply mentioned in his comment, your HTML bit will be echoed at least once, even if `$time == $foo`.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better "collect" everything and print it at once. Keep in mind to set the "stop the loop" condition sometime in the loop itself to avoid an infinite loop.

```
<?php
$html_out='';
do {
    $html_out.='<tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>';
} while ($time !== $foo);
echo $html_out;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternate syntax for do-while but you can do this

```
<?php while($time !== $foo): ?>
    <tr><td><p>some words</p></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: is there any downside to this? It's to my understanding that a do/while executes the code at a different point then a normal while loop - or would it not really matter? :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Check my answer for a correct `do... while` syntax ;)

Comment: In while loop the condition is checked at the starting of the loop and if it is true then the code inside the loop is executed. This process is repeated till the condition becomes false. In case of do while loop the checking of condition is done at the end of the loop. So even if the condition is false, the script inside the loop is executed at least once. This is the basic difference between do while loop and while loop.

Comment: @roberto06 you can do everything like you proposed, however the question was about shorthand syntax

Comment: How is the question about shorthand syntax ? I merely added my answer because, from the comment above,  it seemed like OP wanted a `do... while` loop and not a simple `while`

Comment: well it was implied that he was looking for a shorthand syntax. But I agree. If  OP doesn't care about the way he gets the result then your way will work for do-while well enough